# trying to reload table but giving exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: iphone, uitableview, reload, nsexception

I am having a tableview which i created using iboutlet.and when i am trying to reload table it is giving this exception.
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', `reason: '-[NSCFString objectAtIndex:]:` unrecognized selector sent to instance `0x5949310`'

```
IBOutlet UITableView *tableStudent;
```

here is .h and .m files.

**.h**

```
IBOutlet UITableView *tableStudent;

-(IBAction)enabeluser;
```

**.m**

```
 -(IBAction)enabeluser{
   [tableStudent reloadData];
 }
```

Comment: hey plaace all the code regradig to table view, how s'd we know were is the error

Comment: NSInvalidArgumentException occur when you refer to non-existing object. You might have release datasource or tableview object in the class.

Comment: It seems the data source (seems to be an array) has got released at that time you call *realodData* method.

Comment: are you calling objectatindex method on an array or an nscfstring string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your array has got released at that time you call realodData method.

Answer (score 0):

NSInvalidArgumentException occur when you refer to non-existing object. You might have release datasource or tableview object in the class.